# running multiple cmdline commands or files simultaneously in Raspberry pi through terminal

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, python-3.6, raspberry-pi3

I have created file one which runs a flask server, starts the Alexa sample app and another is a cmdline command which runs port forwarding server.

which are:

led.py, sudo bash startsampleapp.sh, and the command is: autossh -M 0 -R 80:localhost:8000 serveo.net

So I want to run all these three from one file I tried using subprocess, Multiprocessing and os but didn't seem to work it doesn't go ahead of led.py. And this 3 should run simultaneously because to start Alexa I need to run Alexa sample app by this command: "sudo bash startsampleapp.sh" and when we ask Alexa to do something serveo.net will get the request and it will forward it to led.py(flask server).so Please help me regarding this.

I have tried creating a bash file like this:

```
#!usr/bin/bash

python led.py &
sudo bash startsampleapp.sh &
autossh -M 0 -R serveo.serveo.net:localhost:8000 serveo.net
```

It should start them in the parallel process but don't work.

Comment: The first line is missing a slash as the third character.

Comment: Sorry. It is #!/bin/bash And I found the solution I am posting it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was opening 3 terminal and running that 3 things respectively.

I create a bash file main.sh which contained:

```
#!/bin/bash

lxterminal -e python led.py &
lxterminal -e autossh -M 0 -R serveo.serveo.net:80:localhost:8000 serveo.net &
lxterminal -e sudo bash startsampleapp.sh
```

Thanks all.

Killing them can be done through getting the process ID and using sudo killall -9 ID command.